# Meteor xwidgets collection is undefined

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to implement xwidgets (an autoform extensions to do things like autocomplete)

It doesn't work because it pretends the collection to get the autocomplete values is undefined.

I don't understand why it is undefined.

This is what I have:

```
@Contacts = new Meteor.Collection("contacts")
@Tenants = new Meteor.Collection("tenants")
```

This is my form template:

```
template(name="newTenant")
    #newTenant.hidden
        .animated.fadeIn
            h4 Add a new tenant for this space
                .space-12
                +autoForm(collection="Tenants" id="insertTenantForm" type="insert")
                    fieldset
                        +afFieldInput(name="contact_id" references="contacts.lastname" call="contacts" template="tags")
                        +afQuickField name="rent"
                        +afQuickField name="costs"
                        +afQuickField name="entry_date" class="datepicker duration"
                        +afQuickField name="contract_duration" class="duration"
                        +afQuickField name="exit_date" class="datepicker"
                        +afQuickField name="contract_type" options="allowed"
                     .btn-group
                        button(type="submit" id="createTenant" class="btn btn-default") Submit
                        a(href="#" id="cancelNewTenant" class="btn btn-danger") Cancel
            +contentFor "modal"
                +newContact
            each contacts
                .editable(_id="{{_id}}") {{_id}}
```

and these are my helpers:

```
Template.newTenant.helpers
  space_id: -> Router.current().params._id
  contacts: -> Contacts.find()
```

tenants is defined in iron-router. the publications are ok.
contacts is defined correctly (It is browsed in the each block)

But I get following error message on keyup:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'contacts': TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/xwidgets.js?0ba0b616c9af16bc49b0ad59d8e950507492d9e0:629:41
    at null._callback (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?439f867e12888606900664d4463e1b3ee3644e44:818:22)
    at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?f42db198bc25553e9f50ea290229c73093a576b3:3782:12)
    at _.extend.dataVisible (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?f42db198bc25553e9f50ea290229c73093a576b3:3811:10)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?f42db198bc25553e9f50ea290229c73093a576b3:4575:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:11)
    at _.extend._runAfterUpdateCallbacks (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?f42db198bc25553e9f50ea290229c73093a576b3:4574:7)
    at _.extend._livedata_data (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?f42db198bc25553e9f50ea290229c73093a576b3:4564:10)
    at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?f42db198bc25553e9f50ea290229c73093a576b3:3643:12)
```

I guess it's a matter of data context scope but I don't know where it comes from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but at first view I think that `references="contacts.lastname"` should be `references="Contacts.lastname"`.

But to be sure, could I have a clone of the app? Thanks.

- o - O - o -
  Edit:

I have written the next code (in `Template.xautocomplete.helpers` `items`):

```
for item, i in (result or [])
```

instead of:

```
for item, i in result
```

that I think is the responsible of the bug. Let me know if this resolves the problem.

- o - O - o - Edit2:

Sorry, I think it's not well documented. You must have a field named 'name' to the autocomplete populates data. Here's an example of server method:

```
Meteor.methods
    items: (query)->
        items.find(name: {$regex: '^.*'+query+'.*$'}).fetch()
```

and in the code of the autocomplete it uses the data the next way:

```
for item, i in (result or [])
    local_items.insert({name: item.name, index: i, remote_id: item._id})
```

If you don't have a field 'name' in your collection, you can do someting like:

```
Meteor.methods
    items: ->
        ({name: x.field} for x in items.find({}))
```

I think this is the problem.

PD: Now I am not at home and don't have a good connection for skype. If the problem is not solved we can do it.

Comment: It doesn't help. There is a github repository of the app here: https://github.com/ndemoreau/immo. The pages mentioned here are in client/views/tenants/new_tenant.jade/coffee. Thanks!

Comment: Now I have your app running. Could you tell me how to reach the fail, please? (Also I can see _references="contacts.lastname"_ instead of _Contacts.lastname_ in file new_tenant.html.

Comment: It's in new_tenant.jade. new_tenant.html was a try to see whether the problem came from jade or not.

Comment: I have change a little the code and I would like to know if it works for you. Yo have to point to the github instead of _mrt add_ because I have not upload to atmosphere yet.

Comment: Also, with the app running... could you tell me the steps to reproduce the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I understand that it is not very easy for you to reproduce the different steps without the db being seeded. If you want, we can make a little Skype or Hangout and share the screen? My skype id is ndemoreau

Comment: I implemented your new code (only on change right?) I have no error message anymore but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I've put some seed data in the app. The path to follow : click the building "Champery", then click the space "rez", then click "add new tenant". then type "h" in the first input. Thx.